# Android: how to fit EditText's RightView according to the EditText height

Tags: android

I need to set an icon (search icon) to a EditText's `RightView`, I've used the following xml:

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon"
```

The problem is that the RightView doesn't fit inside the EditText, instead the EditText's height changes based on the icon height.. Is it possible to do the opposite, to edit the RightView's height based on the EditText's height?

XML of the EditText:

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regSearch"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Search Test"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:textColor="@color/lowBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon" />
```

Comment: provide your textview code please

Comment: @vishaljangid added but I'm pretty sure there's no way from the XML to achieve what I want

Comment: i think you should use custom edit text or create the search icon image size as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after searching for a while I've came up with the following solution that doesn't need to create any other "hackish" element:

```
regSearch.getViewTreeObserver()
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Drawable img = Registrazione.this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.search_icon);
                img.setBounds(0, 0, regSearch.getMeasuredHeight()-regSearch.getMeasuredHeight()/3, regSearch.getMeasuredHeight()-regSearch.getMeasuredHeight()/3); //you can edit this in order to resize the drawable
                regSearch.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, img, null);
                regSearch.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

This way you can set and edit the dimension of whatever drawable you want, hope it can help someone else because I got stuck on this problem for a while :P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using drawableRight, you can tweak your layout a little bit and have an imageview alongside the edittext, and then you can play with the height and width of the two views. e.g. this can be achieved using a RelativeLayout with the edittext and imageview within:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <EditText android:id="my_edittext"/>
  <ImageView android:toRightOf="@+id/my_edittext"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_edittext"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_edittext"/>
<RelativeLayout/>
```

The alignTop and alignBottom attribute will take care of the height issue you are facing. And toRightOf will put the imageview to the right of the edittext in your layout.

But if you want the imgeview to be over the edittext, you can achieve that too using this layout - just remove the "toRightOf" attribute and add alignParentRight="true" to the ImageView.

NOTE: I've not written the complete xml code here. Let me know if you need any more help with this.

Comment: ty but I didn't want to use other elements in order to achieve the effect, I've posted the solution that worked for me above, thanks anyways! :)